# Where does the random come in for conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}]$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, conditioning, sigma-algebra

For continuous random variables $X, Y$ the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X | Y]$ is itself a random variable. I understood this in the sense that for a realisation of $Y$ we can say

$$
\mathbb{E}[X | Y=y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx =
\frac{1}{f_Y(y)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx.
$$

And so I imagine a random elementary event happening on $\Omega$ that gives a corresponding result to $Y$ and allows conditioning $X$ as above.

The signature would then be something like this

$$\mathbb{E}[X | Y]: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \omega \mapsto \mathbb{E}[X | Y(\omega)]$$

The conditional expectation here is random because $Y$ is a random variable that gives an output to the random occurrences on the magical space $\Omega$.

However in more advanced courses and textbooks I studied on the matter the conditional expectation is often introduced via sub-$\sigma$-algebras and then defined by some characterisation like this:

Let $X \in L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ and $Y \in L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra  of $\mathcal{A}$. Then

$$
Y = \mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}] \quad \iff \quad
\forall F \in \mathcal{F}:
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_F X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_F Y].
$$

These concepts supposedly coincide as $\mathbb{E}[X | Y] = \mathbb{E}[X | \sigma(Y)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}]$ is understood to be a random variable as well. But the interpretation gets lost for me.

The above definition of $\mathbb{E}[X | Y]$ is coherent with the common idea that $\Omega$ is the set of outcomes of some (real) random experiment. Selecting an outcome $Y(\omega)$ allows for the calculation of $\mathbb{E}[X | Y=y]$.

But for $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}]$ it is not at all clear to me how this concept is "calculated". What is $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}](\omega)$?
Can you give a non-trivial (non discrete) example of a random experiment and a continuous random variable such that this expression is understandable and has meaning in the model of that random experiment?

Comment: Just as $X$ is actually a function, $X:\,\omega\mapsto X(\omega)$, $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{F}]$ is also a function (of $\omega$) that is furthermore $\mathcal{F}$-measurable and the closest to $X$. The solution does not have to be a constant function. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/230559/7224

Comment: $\Omega$ is far from being some "magical space:" it has an extremely concrete meaning.  It can represent all individuals in a population, for instance.  Each individual $\omega\in\Omega$ has a definite numerical property $X(\omega).$  *That's obviously not random.*  What *is* random is the process of selecting one individual from the population.  The probability distribution $\mathbb P$ describes the relative chances of selection, thereby endowing $X$ with a distribution, *etc.*

Comment: @Xi'an I understand that it is also a function of $\omega$, but it is not at all clear to me what that law is. I.e. given an $\omega$, what do you do with it?

Comment: @whuber This is clear from basic probability theory. But don't we all have the implicit understanding that elements of $\Omega$ are picked at random? If you eliminate that intuition then all that is left is deterministic relations between deterministic sets and their measures. Sorry if "magical space" offended you, but I don't see how that hyperbole is relevant to the question.

Comment: I cannot discern a definite answerable question.  What kind of responses are you hoping for?

Comment: @whuber if I knew exactly what kind of response I want I would basically already have the answer myself. Would you say this website is only for questions that have to have a precise answer? Are questions on meaning and guidance that more experienced people could provide out of bounds?

Comment: Maybe my recent answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585969 will help?