# How to prove that $\frac{\int_{\{X\in B\}} P(A|X)(\omega)dP(\omega)}{P(X\in B)}=P(A\mid X\in B)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a sample space and $X: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ is a random variable. The conditional probability is given by

$$\frac{1}{P(X\in B)}\int_{\{X\in B\}} P(A|X)(\omega)dP(\omega)=P(A\mid X\in B)$$

for $P( X\in B)>0$. I have seen the above equation in several sources but I have not seen any proof for it. Could you please show me why this is true or direct me to a textbook where it is proved.

Comment: Express probabilities [in terms of expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/450381/919) and then apply the [definition of conditional expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74339/919). You only have to work with the sigma algebra of four elements (as in the link) generated by $X^{-1}(B).$

Comment: @whuber, could you please explain this in an answer?

Comment: I already did, in the second link.

Comment: @whuber, I don't see $\frac{1}{P(X\in B)}\int_{\{X\in B\}} P(A|X)(\omega)dP(\omega)$ anywhere in your link.

Comment: @whuber, how is this related to the link?

Comment: @gbd Think of "heads" as the event $X\in B$ and go from there.

Comment: @whuber how would the LHS look like accourding to your derivation in the link?

Comment: @whuber, I think you may have misunderstood OP's question. I am not sure how the link is related to the question.

Comment: @user3879021 I don't think so.  I am suggesting analyzing the indicator of $A,$ $\mathscr I_A,$ which is a Bernoulli random variable whose expectation is $\Pr(A),$ and conditioning it on the Bernoulli variable $\mathscr{I}_{X^{-1}(B)}.$

Comment: @whuber, can you show that in an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is a one-liner, but that's disingenuous because (as you can see) it's going to take me some time to get to it!

Before setting out, let's establish a general yet accurate way to visualize what's going on.

#### Seeing things

[image: Figure 1: a dissection]

This figure schematically draws $\Omega$ as the interior of a rectangle.

When $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ is any function, it has a "contour map" of level sets of the form $X^{-1}(b)$ for any contour level $b\in\mathbb R.$  Clearly, no distinct level sets may intersect and so they partition (a set-theoretic term), "dissect" (a statistical term), or "foliate" (a topological term) $\Omega.$  For our purposes the geometrical details of this dissection won't matter, so I have felt free to sketch each of the level curves as a vertical line segment, even though they needn't have the same shapes, sizes, or cardinalities.

[image: Figure 2 showing some events]

Below, I will be discussing two kinds of *events:* measurable subsets of $\Omega.$  $\mathcal A$ is an arbitrary event in $\Omega.$  Because it could be anywhere, and we are free in this schematic to re-order the points within each of the vertical lines of the dissection any way we please (and separately from each other), I have drawn things so that the intersections of $\mathcal A$ with the level curves $X^{-1}(b)$ are segments originating at the bottom (dashed) axis.  In this fashion we may conceive, with wide generality and accuracy, of *any* (single) event as being a region under some curve.

The event $\mathcal B$ bordered on the left and right by dashed lines is special because it is comprised of *entire* level curves.  This means it is of the form $X^{-1}(B)$ where $B\subset \mathbb R$ is the set of "heights" of $X$ within $\mathcal B$ on the contour map.  **This helps us visualize the distinction between arbitrary events and events relative to the subalgebra generated by $X.$**  The latter are all unions of level sets: collections of vertical strips.

It will do no harm to think of the probability measure $\mathbb P$ as being *uniform:* thus, *areas* in this figure represent probabilities, with the entire rectangle understood as having a unit area.

Finally, here is a sketch of the conditional expectation of the indicator function $\mathscr I_\mathcal A$ with respect to this dissection.  (Recall that $\mathscr I_\mathcal A$ assigns the value $1$ to all points in $\mathcal A$ and the value $0$ to all other points.)

[image: Figure 3]

The horizontal line labeled with the conditional expectation $E[\mathscr I_\mathcal A\mid X\in B]$ is drawn at the *average height of $A$ within $\mathcal B.$*  As we are taught in Calculus (for real functions), that average is the integral of the height divided by the width of the strip representing $\mathcal B.$  That is, *we have replaced the area of an arbitrary shape $\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B$ by a rectangle of the same area, spanning the same width as $\mathcal B$ in the horizontal direction.*

> This height equals the probability of $\mathcal A$ conditional on $\mathcal B.$

If you have managed to follow my descriptions, this is **obvious** in the picture, for if you were to throw darts randomly (and uniformly) at it, the (limiting) fraction of darts landing within $\mathcal B$ that are also in $\mathcal A$ is the same as the (limiting) fraction landing within $\mathcal B$ at heights between $0$ and $E[\mathscr I_\mathcal A\mid \mathscr B].$

Let's do this again in algebraic notation.  As is common in such measure-theoretic situations, this result is a matter of notation and definitions, so let's begin with these simple preliminaries.

#### Conditioning on a sigma-algebra

When  $\mathfrak G\subset \mathfrak F$ is a subalgebra of the probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak F, \mathbb P),$ a [*conditional expectation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) $E$ for any integrable $\mathfrak F$-measurable random variable $Y$ is its "projection" $E[Y\mid\mathfrak G]$  onto some $\mathfrak G$-measurable random variable $E[Y\mid \mathfrak G]$ for which

$$\int_{\mathscr B} Y\mathrm d \mathbb P = \int_{\mathscr B} E[Y\mid\mathfrak G]\mathrm d \mathbb P\tag{1}$$

for any $\mathfrak G$-measurable event $\mathscr B.$

Applying $(1)$ to $Y = \mathscr I_\mathcal A,$ the indicator of some $\mathfrak F$-measurable event $\mathcal A,$ gives

$$\Pr(\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B) = \int_{\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B} \mathrm{d}\mathbb P = \int_{\mathcal B} \mathscr I_{\mathcal A}\mathrm\, d \mathbb P = \int_{\mathcal B}E[\mathscr I_{\mathcal A}\mid \mathfrak G]\mathrm d \mathbb P.\tag{2}$$

#### Conditioning on an event

When $\Pr(\mathcal B)\ne 0,$ according to the [definition of conditioning on a single event $\mathcal B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditioning_on_an_event),

$$\Pr(\mathcal A\mid \mathcal B) = \frac{\Pr(\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B)}{\Pr(\mathcal B)}.
\tag{3}$$

Substituting the conditional expectation expression $(2)$ for $\Pr(\mathcal A \cap \mathcal B)$ into $(3)$ yields

$$\Pr(\mathcal A \mid \mathcal B) = \frac{1}{\Pr(\mathcal B)} \int_{\mathcal B}E[\mathscr I_{\mathcal A}\mid \mathfrak G]\mathrm d \mathbb P.\tag{4}$$

#### Measure-theoretic definition of conditional probability

Apply the preceding remarks to the case where $X$ is a $\mathfrak F$-measurable random variable, $B$ is a real Borel set, $\mathcal B = X^{-1}(B),$ and $\mathfrak G$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X.$  The conditional probability is [defined in terms of expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_probability) as

$$\Pr(\mathcal A \mid X \in B) = \int_{X^{-1}(B)} E[\mathscr I_{\mathcal A}\mid \mathfrak G]\mathrm d \mathbb P = \int_{X^{-1}(B)} \Pr(\mathcal A \mid X)\mathrm d \mathbb P.\tag{5}$$

#### Answer to the question

Since $\Pr(\mathcal B) = \Pr(X \in B),$ the statement in the question is a restatement of $(4)$ using $(5).$

Comment: Damn. That's insightful. +1.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.  However, my confusion actually comes from equation $(3)$. Why is $(3)$ correct? I have studied $(3)$ through out my statistics courses but have never seen a (measure-theoretic) proof of it.

Comment: @AlSon41 I realize this is not immediately useful to you, but I recommend [Athreya and Lahiri 2006](https://www.amazon.ca/Measure-Theory-Probability-Krishna-Athreya/dp/038732903X) as a technical reference.

Comment: @Galen, Does it contain a proof of $(3)$?

Comment: (3) is a *definition.*

Comment: @whuber, is there a reason for this definition? I know that it works but surely there must be a reason or a prove?

Comment: @AlSon41 Definitions never have proof, but a motivation is desirable. I'm motivated by the notion of [conditioning on an event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event).

Comment: The simplest motivation I know of appeals to the [tickets-in-a-box model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95993).  Conditioning on $\mathcal B$ merely removes all non-$\mathcal B$ tickets from the box.  The conditional probability $\Pr(\mathcal A\mid \mathcal B)$ is the fraction of $\mathcal A$ tickets left.